# SAM-D21 Clock On Demand does not wake up the MCU from Standby

Tags: arm, power-consumption, sleep, freertos

I am using SAMD21 with FreeRTOS. I am putting the system on sleep level **Standby** and relying on a TC that works as a systick for the tickless FreeRtos to wake up the MCU however, when the debugger isn't connected (which it shouldn't be) the MCU goes to sleep and never wakes up.

[image]

I have tried it with the internal 8M and external 32K and had no lock. The only clock which the CPU can wake up from sleep with is ULP32K which is always on so **On Demand** doesn't really mean much in that case.

This is the snippets of the TC and my Clock configurations:

```
// From conf_clock.h
/* SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC8M configuration - Internal 8MHz oscillator */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC8M_PRESCALER              SYSTEM_OSC8M_DIV_1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC8M_ON_DEMAND              true  // <--
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC8M_RUN_IN_STANDBY         false // <--

/* Configure GCLK generator 5 */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_ENABLE                true 
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_RUN_IN_STANDBY        true // <--
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC8M 
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false


// From tickless.c
void vPortSetupTimerInterrupt(void)
{
    // Struct for configuring TC
    struct tc_config tcconf;
    // Set up configuration values
    tc_get_config_defaults(&tcconf);
    tcconf.clock_source     = GCLK_GENERATOR_5;
    tcconf.counter_size    = TC_COUNTER_SIZE_32BIT;
    tcconf.run_in_standby  = true;                       // <--
    tcconf.clock_prescaler = TC_CLOCK_PRESCALER_DIV1;
    tcconf.wave_generation = TC_WAVE_GENERATION_MATCH_FREQ;

    // Initialize the TC
    tc_init(&tc, TICK_TC, &tcconf);

    // Register and enable callback for freeRTOS tick handler
    tc_register_callback(&tc, (tc_callback_t) xPortSysTickHandler, TC_CALLBACK_CC_CHANNEL0);
    tc_enable_callback(&tc, TC_CALLBACK_CC_CHANNEL0);

    // Set top value equal to one OS tick
    tc_set_count_value(&tc, 0);
    tc_set_top_value(&tc, TIMER_RELOAD_VALUE_ONE_TICK);

    // Enable the timer
    tc_enable(&tc);
}
```

What I am missing here.

Is this the same issue people are talking here -> http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/samd21-samd21e16b-sporadically-locks-and-does-not-wake-standby-sleep-mode

Just to clarify, the sleep level **IDLE_2** works and CPU can recover from sleep successfully.

Comment: In order to determine whether Errata 10416 is relevant, try running your tests with the TC peripheral in 8bit mode. According to the datasheet, none of the registers are read-synchronized in 8bit mode.